# installing cheerio package in the local meteor project directory

Tags: node.js

I need to install [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) so that it can be used locally in my Meteor project. So I cd into my meteor project directory and did `npm install cheerio`

After installing, it gave these messages at the end;

```
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/empl1/Documents/meteor/microscope/package.json'
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON microscope No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON microscope No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON microscope No README data
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON microscope No license field.
```

I do not see cheerio in projectDirectory/.meteor/local/packages or in projectDirectory/.meteor/local/versions

How can I fix this issue? Thanks

```
microscope$npm install cheerio                
/Users/empl1/Documents/meteor/microscope
└─┬ cheerio@0.20.0 
  ├─┬ css-select@1.2.0 
  │ ├── boolbase@1.0.0 
  │ ├── css-what@2.1.0 
  │ ├── domutils@1.5.1 
  │ └── nth-check@1.0.1 
  ├─┬ dom-serializer@0.1.0 
  │ └── domelementtype@1.1.3 
  ├── entities@1.1.1 
  ├─┬ htmlparser2@3.8.3 
  │ ├── domelementtype@1.3.0 
  │ ├── domhandler@2.3.0 
  │ ├── entities@1.0.0 
  │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.1.14 
  │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.2 
  │   ├── inherits@2.0.1 
  │   ├── isarray@0.0.1 
  │   └── string_decoder@0.10.31 
  ├─┬ jsdom@7.2.2 
  │ ├── abab@1.0.3 
  │ ├── acorn@2.7.0 
  │ ├── acorn-globals@1.0.9 
  │ ├── cssom@0.3.1 
  │ ├── cssstyle@0.2.34 
  │ ├─┬ escodegen@1.8.0 
  │ │ ├── esprima@2.7.2 
  │ │ ├── estraverse@1.9.3 
  │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2 
  │ │ ├─┬ optionator@0.8.1 
  │ │ │ ├── deep-is@0.1.3 
  │ │ │ ├── fast-levenshtein@1.1.3 
  │ │ │ ├── levn@0.3.0 
  │ │ │ ├── prelude-ls@1.1.2 
  │ │ │ ├── type-check@0.3.2 
  │ │ │ └── wordwrap@1.0.0 
  │ │ └─┬ source-map@0.2.0 
  │ │   └── amdefine@1.0.0 
  │ ├── nwmatcher@1.3.7 
  │ ├── parse5@1.5.1 
  │ ├─┬ request@2.72.0 
  │ │ ├── aws-sign2@0.6.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ aws4@1.3.2 
  │ │ │ └─┬ lru-cache@4.0.1 
  │ │ │   ├── pseudomap@1.0.2 
  │ │ │   └── yallist@2.0.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ bl@1.1.2 
  │ │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.0.6 
  │ │ │   ├── isarray@1.0.0 
  │ │ │   ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.6 
  │ │ │   └── util-deprecate@1.0.2 
  │ │ ├── caseless@0.11.0 
  │ │ ├─┬ combined-stream@1.0.5 
  │ │ │ └── delayed-stream@1.0.0 
  │ │ ├── extend@3.0.0 
  │ │ ├── forever-agent@0.6.1 
  │ │ ├─┬ form-data@1.0.0-rc4 
  │ │ │ └── async@1.5.2 
  │ │ ├─┬ har-validator@2.0.6 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3 
  │ │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1 
  │ │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 
  │ │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0 
  │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0 
  │ │ │ │ ├── strip-ansi@3.0.1 
  │ │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ commander@2.9.0 
  │ │ │ │ └── graceful-readlink@1.0.1 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ is-my-json-valid@2.13.1 
  │ │ │ │ ├── generate-function@2.0.0 
  │ │ │ │ ├─┬ generate-object-property@1.2.0 
  │ │ │ │ │ └── is-property@1.0.2 
  │ │ │ │ ├── jsonpointer@2.0.0 
  │ │ │ │ └── xtend@4.0.1 
  │ │ │ └─┬ pinkie-promise@2.0.1 
  │ │ │   └── pinkie@2.0.4 
  │ │ ├─┬ hawk@3.1.3 
  │ │ │ ├── boom@2.10.1 
  │ │ │ ├── cryptiles@2.0.5 
  │ │ │ ├── hoek@2.16.3 
  │ │ │ └── sntp@1.0.9 
  │ │ ├─┬ http-signature@1.1.1 
  │ │ │ ├── assert-plus@0.2.0 
  │ │ │ ├─┬ jsprim@1.2.2 
  │ │ │ │ ├── extsprintf@1.0.2 
  │ │ │ │ ├── json-schema@0.2.2 
  │ │ │ │ └── verror@1.3.6 
  │ │ │ └─┬ sshpk@1.8.2 
  │ │ │   ├── asn1@0.2.3 
  │ │ │   ├── assert-plus@1.0.0 
  │ │ │   ├─┬ dashdash@1.13.1 
  │ │ │   │ └── assert-plus@1.0.0 
  │ │ │   ├── ecc-jsbn@0.1.1 
  │ │ │   ├─┬ getpass@0.1.5 
  │ │ │   │ └── assert-plus@1.0.0 
  │ │ │   ├── jodid25519@1.0.2 
  │ │ │   ├── jsbn@0.1.0 
  │ │ │   └── tweetnacl@0.13.3 
  │ │ ├── is-typedarray@1.0.0 
  │ │ ├── isstream@0.1.2 
  │ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 
  │ │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.10 
  │ │ │ └── mime-db@1.22.0 
  │ │ ├── node-uuid@1.4.7 
  │ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.8.1 
  │ │ ├── qs@6.1.0 
  │ │ ├── stringstream@0.0.5 
  │ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.4.2 
  │ ├── sax@1.2.1 
  │ ├── symbol-tree@3.1.4 
  │ ├── tough-cookie@2.2.2 
  │ ├── webidl-conversions@2.0.1 
  │ ├─┬ whatwg-url-compat@0.6.5 
  │ │ └── tr46@0.0.3 
  │ └── xml-name-validator@2.0.1 
  └── lodash@4.11.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have package.json file in project folder, you should generate it, before installing NPM packages. Run this command:

meteor npm init

Then answer questions about your project and default package.json will be generated.

After this you can install cheerio.

As an alternative, you can install Cheerio not from NPM, but from Athmosphere (Meteor packaging system):

meteor add mrt:cheerio

As a rule, first try to find needed package wrapper in Athmosphere and install from NPM only if Athmosphere does not have required package.

Comment: It as asking `entry point: (index.js)` what is that for? I read in the npm help json but could not understand how to answer this question

Comment: This is the main file of your project. Usually it's index.js. But probable in your case it could be "microscope.js"